# sheaves with free abelian stalks over compact space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

The question concerns a sheaf $S$ of abelian groups over a compact space $X$. Suppose each stalk $S_x$ is finite rank free. Is the group of global sections free?

Comment: Well, each stalk $S_x$ is generated by a finite number of sections over an open containing $x$. We can cover $X$ by such opens, and then find a finite subcover. This should, I hope, give some information about the group of global sections.

Comment: Is your space at least Hausdorff or you are working in an algebraic category?

Comment: For the constant sheaf $\mathbb Z$, it is true: the global sections may be identified with a subgroup of the group of bounded functions $X\to\mathbb Z$, and the latter group is free (G. Nöbeling, Verallgemeinerung eines Satzes von Herrn E. Specker, Invent. Math. 6 (1968) 41-55).

Comment: The space is not necessarily Hausdorff, but an affirmative answer in the Hausdorff case would be interesting. 

The case of the constant sheaf mentioned is the motivation for this question. Specker's proof of freeness in that case doesn't seem to go over very well to this more general case. 

Comment: Interesting question. Concerning a-fortiori's comment, here is a online-copy of Nöbeling's article http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=PPN356556735_0006&DMDID=dmdlog9

Comment: I believe this is true if for every point of $X$, there is a neighborhood on which sections of $S$ are free (because then global sections are a subgroup of $\bigoplus S(U)$ where the $U$ are a finite collection of such neighborhoods covering $X$.

It is also true if global sections are finitely generated (because there is an injection $S(X) \to \prod S_x$ which is torsion free).

Unfortunately, I can't find any examples of sheaves with finite rank free stalks which don't have these properties...  